# split string and get the value using regex from a complicated string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like this `{"product_tags":"yin_yang,yin yang"}`.
what I want to do is just avoid everything else other than **yin yang**. There is two strings but I just want the first one.

Note that in some cases even if the second string is not available I want to get the same result. And that string might change so it is not necessary that the string will be always `yin_yang` sometimes it can be `motorbike` or anything else.

Comment: please note in some cases even if the second string is not available i want to get the same result. and that string might change so it is not necessary that the string will be always yin_yang sometimes it can be motorbike or anything else.

Comment: This is not clear, you want some method to transform `{"product_tags":"xxxxxxxx,yin yang"}` into "xxxxxxxx"?

Comment: you want first string or second string after `:`

Comment: yes you are currect i want the first which is xxxxxxxx

Comment: and this string can be **{"product_tags":"yin_yang"}** as well?

Comment: yes please it can be that as well.. i just want the value coming after :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Look like JSON String Use the [JSONParser](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) in java

```
JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(STRING);
String value=jobject.getString("product_tags");
```

EDITED

Using REGEX

```
 String json="{\"product_tags\":\"yin_yang,yin yang\"}";
    json=json.replaceAll("([{}]+)", "");
    String value[]=json.split(":");
    System.out.print(value[1]);
```

Comment: sorry mate its not a json string and its not a json array.. its just a value inside one column in a database. and i want to get that value from database but need to avoid all other strings other than the one coming after :

Comment: @sarath yes, that' ok. the `new JSONObject(<your string>)` will create the `JSONObject()` to typecast it.

Comment: @sarath you can get like that value using this code.regex may not be accurate.

Comment: @sarath I have Updated my answer using regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer to parse your string

```
String str ="{\"product_tags\":\"yin_yang,yin yang\"}";
StringTokenizer to = new StringTokenizer(str,":}");
while(to.hasMoreTokens()){
    String firstString = (String) to.nextElement();
    String secondString = (String) to.nextElement();
System.out.print(secondString);
}
```

Comment: secondString is not accessible out size the while loop;